# Add calculator from other website to my website

Tags: html, calculator

I want to add [this calculator](http://www.superskinnyme.com/bf.html) to my website html. What code should I write to my html? Can I do it without the extra javascript and css? Thanks in advance

Comment: Trying using iframes in an I frame you can load the calculator <iframe name="iframe1" src="target.html"></iframe>  <a href="link.html" target="iframe1">link</a>

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it but these are the two best options:

1. Use iframe - you don't need much extra javascript code, but you'll have to fiddle with the css and positioning as the calculator is in the middle of an empty page. As LearningPhase said, use `<iframe src="http://www.superskinnyme.com/bf.html"></iframe>` + styles.
2. Copy and paste HTML block (table) that includes the calculator, and copy the javascript code as well. You can access them through "View page source":

Javascript:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.superskinnyme.com/js/fatcalc.js"></script>`.

Table:

```
<table width="480px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="http://www.superskinnyme.com/blog/wp-content/themes/repro/images/bg1.jpg" align="left">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td align="left"><form>
      <table width="490" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="#F8FDFF" class="wp" background="http://www.superskinnyme.com/blog/wp-content/themes/repro/images/bg1.jpg">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td align="right" class="style4">Gender&nbsp;</td>
          <td><label for="s1">
            <input type="radio" id="s1" name="s" value="m" onclick="sex(this.form)">
            <span class="wp">            Male</span></label>
              <span class="wp">
              <label for="s2">              </label>
              </span>
              <label for="s2">
              <input type="radio" id="s2" name="s" value="f" onclick="sex(this.form)">
              <span class="wp">Female</span></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" class="wp"><strong>Preferred measurement&nbsp;</strong></td>
          <td><label for="d1">
            <input type="radio" id="d1" name="d" value="1">
            <span class="wp">Centimetres</span></label>
              <label for="d2">
              <input type="radio" id="d2" name="d" value="2.54">
              <span class="wp">Inches</span></label>
              <span class="wp">
              <label for="d2"></label>
              <label for="d2"> </label>
              </span>
              <label for="d2"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right" class="wp"><strong>Height&nbsp;</strong></div></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="h" name="h" size="6" class="calcbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" class="wp"><strong>Neck&nbsp;</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="n" name="n" size="6" class="calcbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><strong class="wp">Waist</strong>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="w" name="w" size="6" class="calcbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" class="wp"><strong>Hips</strong>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="r" name="r" size="6" disabled="disabled" class="calcbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calc(this.form);return false;" name="button2" class="calcbutton" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:#305996;vertical-align:middle">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="clearForm(this.form)" class="calcbuttons" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:#305996; vertical-align:middle"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="19" colspan="2" align="center" class="bigbold">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="19" colspan="2" bgcolor="#DDDDDD" id="mus"><div align="center"><span class="smallw">RESULT</span></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><strong>BODY FAT </strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="f" name="f" size="6" readonly="readonly" class="calcboxa"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```